# Strange variable-sized array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

Reading [this Skip List implementation](http://256.com/sources/skip/docs/skipLists.c) I came across this code fragment:

```
typedef struct nodeStructure{
    keyType key;
    valueType value;
    node forward[1]; /* variable sized array of forward pointers */
    };
```

To me it seems that `forward[1]` denotes a one element array. And the comment calls it a *variable sized array*.

Do I misunderstand something or this is just a mistake in the source I'm reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common trick for the older C compilers (before C99): compilers allowed you to dereference elements past the end of `forward`'s declared length when it is the last element of the `struct`; you could then `malloc` enough memory for the additional `node` elements, like this:

```
nodeStructure *ptr = malloc(sizeof(nodeStructure)+4*sizeof(node));
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) { // The fifth element is part of the struct
    ptr->forward[i] = ...
}
free(ptr);
```

The trick lets you embed arrays of variable size in a structure without a separate dynamic allocation. An alternative solution would be to declare `node *forward`, but then you'd need to `malloc` and `free` it separately from the `nodeStructure`, unnecessarily doubling the number of `malloc`s and potentially increasing memory fragmentation:

Here is how the above fragment would look without the hack:

```
typedef struct nodeStructure{
    keyType key;
    valueType value;
    node *forward;
};

nodeStructure *ptr = malloc(sizeof(nodeStructure));
ptr->forward = malloc(5*sizeof(node));
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    ptr->forward[i] = ...
}
free(ptr->forward);
free(ptr);
```

**EDIT** (in response to comments by Adam Rosenfield): C99 lets you define arrays with no size, like this: `node forward[];` This is called *flexible array member*, it is defined in the section 6.7.2.1.16 of the C99 standard.

Comment: @What is the use of such an obscure syntax? Does it give any benefits?

Comment: @ovgolovin Please see the edit, I added an info on the benefit of this trick (fewer allocations).

Comment: Please, could you write how allocation can be done via `node *forward` (if it's not too long). I think it will be helpful not only for me, but for the other newbies who are learning C.

Comment: @ovgolovin Sure, no problem - please take a look.

Comment: The C standard lets you do this?  I always thought it was a hack that only worked because compilers arranged structs so similarly.  Since `forward` is defined as a 1-element array, `forward[10]` is outside the array and thus should technically trigger UB.

Comment: @cHao Yes, `forward[10]` was and is undefined behavior, but the nineties used to be such simpler times.

Comment: It's worth noting that C99 added a feature called the *flexible array member* which is very similar, except you declare the array with indeterminate size: `node forward[];`

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Thanks, Adam, I edited the answer to include the information from your comment.

Comment: Could you also write a code which would use *flexible array member*? Because it seems to me `nodeStructure *ptr = malloc(sizeof(nodeStructure)+4*sizeof(node))` could be replaced with another syntax to declare the array size, or will it still be done through tinkering with `malloc`?

Comment: @ovgolovin Yes, you use the same trick, except you do not subtract one from the intended array size (i.e. for a five-element array you use `malloc(sizeof(nodeStructure)+5*sizeof(node))`, not `malloc(sizeof(nodeStructure)+4*sizeof(node))`. Prior to flexible arrays it was very confusing (I made this mistake in my first answer, using 5 instead of 4, and corrected it only in my last edit).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: By my understanding of the C standard, the struct hack relies upon Undefined Behavior, since given a struct member of e.g. `char foo[2]` the maximum amount one is allowed to add to `&foo` would be either 2 (the declared size) or ([end of allocated space] - `foo`), *whichever is less*; such a rule would allow a compiler to e.g. replace `foo[expr]` with `expr ? foo[1] : foo[0]` if the latter operation would be faster.  In practice, I suspect compilers would disable any such optimizations with indirectly-accessed structs that end with a single-element array, but...

Comment: ...I don't know of anything in any standard that would require them to do so.  Specifying a size which was larger than one would ever need would seem more legitimate, but some compilers won't allow the declaration of structs beyond a certain size (e.g. 64K) whether or not any "full-sized" instances would ever be created.  Some older compilers allow an array size of 0; I wonder why the standard didn't simply follow their lead (a zero-sized array could be useful not only as a flexible-array member, but also to enforce alignment of the next member and alias a pointer to it).

Answer (score 5):

It is called the *struct hack*. It is the *old* form of the *flexible array member* introduced in C99.

This has been used in the past to mimic a variable array in the last member of a structure but it is not a strictly conformning construct in C.

Answer (score 3):

This is a program paradigm in C that you will see sometimes. When allocating the structure, you will allocate sizeof(struct nodeStructure + numNodes * sizeof(node)).

This allows you to have multiple forward nodes for the struct, even though it is only declared to have one. It's a bit of an ugly hack, but it works.

Typically, when you do this, there will also be a filed called 'count' or something, so that you know how many extra entries are after the node.

Comment: Have spent a few minutes trying to find count. But haven't. Eventually it dawned on me that values abouve `numNodes` won't be accessed at all (because of how pointers to this node are kept: this node will be accessed only from the levels of the skip list that itself has as well in the array).

Answer (score 2):

The data structure implementation is most likely written against the C90 standard, which did not have *flexible array members* (added in C99). At that time, it was common to use a 1- or even 0-sized(*) array at the end of a struct to allow access to a dynamically variable number of elements there.

The comment should not be interpreted as meaning C99-style variable length arrays; besides, in C99, the idiomatic and standard-conformant definition for member `forward` would be `node forward[];`. A type such as `struct nodeStructure` with such a member is then called an *incomplete type*. You can define a pointer to it, but you cannot define a variable of this type or take its size, all operations that `node forward[0]` or `node forward[1]` allow, although these operations arguably mismatch the programmer's intent.

(*) 0-sized arrays are forbidden by the standard but GCC accepted these as an extension for precisely this use.