# Char with a variable length

Tags: c, struct, char, dynamic-memory-allocation, variable-length-array

Is it possible to define a `char` with a variable length?

I have a `char` "name" (member of a `struct` named "person") with a length of 25 but I want it to be a variable length between the values 1 and 25, because I want to generate random strings of that `char` with different sizes and not always with the same length (25). One of the parameters of the method is `sizeof(n.name)`.

Note: `n` is a `struct` (`struct person n`).

The `struct` "person" is defined this way:

```
    struct person{
       int c; 
       char name[25];
    };
```

Anyone?

Comment: why don't you use char* name ?

Comment: because I want to limit the lenght of the char between 1 and 25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct person{
   int c; 
   char name[]; /* Variable length array */
};
```

I think this should serve your purpose.

Else you can have dynamic memory allocation using

```
char *name;
```

`name` is a pointer and memory should be allocated and it can be done using `malloc()`

Comment: It is possible to limit the lenght of the char between 1 and 25?

Comment: @Zombie Before writing the value to `name` validate the string length

Answer (score 5):

You can use a flexible array. It must be the last data member of a structure.

```
struct person{
   int c; 
   char name[];
};
```

The memory for a structure with a flexible array has to be allocated dynamically.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the
>   structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that
>   it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply. Howev
>   er, when a . (or ->) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer
>   to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand
>   names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the
>   longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the
>   structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the
>   array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this
>   would differ from that of the replacement array. If this array would
>   have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior
>   is undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to
>   generate a pointer one past it.

And there is an example of its using

```
20 EXAMPLE 2 After the declaration:
struct s { int n; double d[]; };
the structure struct s has a flexible array member d. A typical way to use this is:
int m = /* some value */;
struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
and assuming that the call to malloc succeeds, the object pointed to by p behaves, for most purposes, as if
p had been declared as:
struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
(there are circumstances in which this equivalence is broken; in particular, the offsets of member d might
not be the same).
```

Or you could declare a pointer to char and dynamically allocate only the array itself

```
struct person{
       int c; 
       char *name;
    };
```

Comment: But that way how can I use "sizeof(n.name)" as a parameter in my method to generate random strings if the char "name" doens't have a size associated?

Comment: @Zombie You should store the size of the array either in some varaible or a data member of the structure.

Answer (score 3):

`char[25]` lets you store C strings of length between zero and 24, inclusive (one character is needed for `'\0'` terminator).

You can use one of two solutions:

- Use a flexible array member, or
- Use a pointer.

The first solution lets you keep the `name` together with the rest of the `struct`, but you would not be able to make arrays of these `struct`s:

```
struct person{
     int c; 
     char name[];
};
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296797/335858) for more information on flexible array members. You need a compiler compatible with C99 to use flexible array members.

The second solution takes slightly more memory, but the size of your `struct` does not change, making it possible to use it in an array:

```
struct person{
     int c; 
     char *name;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way to do this is to use the strings library and declare the variable 'name' of type string.

```
#include<string>   

 struct person{
           int c; 
           string name;
        };
```

Comment: This is a question about C; `string` and `#include <string>` are only available in C++.